# GMAIL: Is it possible to search that I haven't replied to email within 24 hrs

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to finding those email which was not reply by me with 24 hrs. Please help with the filter or google script to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this filter:

```
newer_than:1d AND -from:me
```

**What it does?**

- filter new mails within 24hours (1day) using `newer_than:1d` operator.
- filter mails that was not replied yet by me using `-from:me`

> When you reply to an email, it is expected to have an email where in you are the sender. "from:your@email.com" will be visible in the thread. By using `-from` we are excluding all emails that has from:your@email.com (which has your reply)

**Reference:**
[Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)